# Unable to break for loop in unity which causes it to freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 public void FixedUpdate()
       {
        
        for (int direction = 1; direction < 5;direction++ )
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                direction = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                direction = 2;
                continue;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                direction = 3;
                continue;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            {
                direction = 4;
                continue;
            }
            if (direction == 1)
            {
                RB.velocity = transform.up * speed;
                continue;

            }
            else if (direction == 2)
            {
                RB.velocity = -transform.up * speed;
                continue;
            }
            else if (direction == 3)
            {
                RB.velocity = -transform.right * speed;
                continue;
            }
            else if (direction == 4)
            {
                RB.velocity = transform.right * speed;
                continue;
            }
            break;
```

This the code I worte for changing the direction of bullet in for loop and trying to break it but it doesn't break at all I know that I have to attach the script to unity editor but i don't know how to break the loop while debuging

Answer (score 0):

What is it that your code is meant to do? To be frank you should rewrite it, but you can solve this problem in particular by removing all the "continue" and "break" statements. What's happening is (if you are pressing Up for example) your loop is running with `direction == 1`, your code detects it and continues the loop with `direction == 2`. Then you detect Up again and set `direction` to 1. This repeats forever.

But really, I think you want to check for each arrow independently. That needs no loop and no `else`. Just write the code to check each arrow key.

Comment: i did that but when i press up and shoot bullet goes up but when i change my direction say for example i turned left after shooting my bullet upwards then the bullet turns and moves left.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the variable you are you using for the loop. Don't assign any value to it because you will risk having an endless loop.

```
for (int direction; direction < 5; direction++){
   direction = 1;
}
```

This loop will never stop.

Also, `continue;` statement will ensure that the rest of the code block will not execute hence you will never reach `break;` at the end there, in other words, once `continue;` is reached it will skip to the next iteration.
I suggest you remove the loop and assign your direction variable within the update() method. Take a look at this : https://answers.unity.com/questions/409507/eliminating-input-loss.html

Comment: i have to assign value else it shows the error Use of unassigned local variable 'direction'

Answer (score 0):

The **FixedUpdate** function is called in fixed intervals by default, hence you do not have to introduce a for-loop for the purpose you mentioned. You can directly check for the input keys in the function body.

You can also change the default time between calls from the script or navigate to:

`Edit > Settings > Time > Fixed Timestep`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write what your function is trying to do is:

```
void FixedUpdate() => RB.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```